# Abp framework Blazor UI 404 Notfound page

Tags: blazor, abp

I'm using ABP framework blazor UI and I need to customize the 404 not found page, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `Volo.BasicTheme\src\Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Components.Web.BasicTheme\Themes\Basic\App.razor`
File

## Solution:

easy way to do this is to fetch BasicTheme Modules source code
`abp add-module Volo.BasicTheme --with-source-code --add-to-solution-file`

Then edit the file manually in
`<YourSolutionFolder>\modules\Volo.BasicTheme\src\Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Components.Web.BasicTheme\Themes\Basic\App.razor`

example:

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@using Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Theming.Routing
@inject IOptions<AbpRouterOptions> RouterOptions
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="RouterOptions.Value.AppAssembly"
            AdditionalAssemblies="RouterOptions.Value.AdditionalAssemblies">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                *** <p>New not found Page Content.</p> ***
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `ErrorView.razor` component by following [this](https://docs.abp.io/en/commercial/latest/themes/lepton-x/blazor?UI=BlazorServer#customization) if you are using leptonx theme which gets invoked in `App.razor`